# Slug is null with Netlify CMS

Tags: markdown, netlify, netlify-cms

I'm trying to get Netlify CMS setup, and running into issues when I use it to create new markdown files.  I tried to read through the docs to get it configured correctly but something doesn't seem to be adding up.  Part of the issue seems to come from the fact that I have my own slug field that I use, and the docs say I can use `fields.slug` to get around conflicts, but it still puts in null when I try to use it.

**Relevant parts of config.yml**

```
collections:
  - name: "staff"
    label: "Staff Members"
    label_singular: "Staff Member"
    summary: "{{firstName}} {{lastName}}"
    folder: "content/staff"
    create: true
    slug: "{{fields.slug}}"
    media_folder: ""
    public_folder: ""
    path: "{{fields.slug}}"
    sortable_fields: ["frontmatter.email"]
    editor:
      preview: true
    fields:
      - { label: "Type", name: "type", widget: "string" }
      - {
          label: "Slug",
          name: "slug",
          widget: "string",
          pattern:
            [
              "^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$",
              "A slug can have no spaces or special characters",
            ],
          required: true,
        }
      - { label: "First Name", name: "firstName", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Last Name", name: "lastName", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Email", name: "email", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown" }
```

**What the markdown should look like:**

```
---
type: "staff"
slug: "jdoe"
firstName: "John"
lastName: "Doe"
email: "fake@email.com"
---

I do stuff.
```

**What I get from Netlify CMS:**

```
---
type: staff
slug: jdoe
firstName: John
lastName: Doe
email: fake@email.com
---

I do stuff.
```

The filename ends up being `.md`, just the extension, no filename.  I did manage to get it to record the slug in the actual md, but the filename is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

Change `slug: "{{fields.slug}}"` to `slug: "{{slug}}"`

This will use the title field slug-ified for the file name. You can still have your custom slug field in your field list for other uses.